# Player Input JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I got a little problem which occupies me for hours.

I want the player to make an input during the game that I will then further use. But I don't know how to do this...

Tried `JOptionPane`, `JTextField` and `Scanner`. `Scanner` worked, but I want it without the use of the console :I

So, here's my code:

Window:

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Window
{
    public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Z-Stories");
    public static JLabel Label = new JLabel ("<html></html>", JLabel.CENTER);
    public static String LabelText;

    public Window()
    {
        Label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
        frame.setSize(1920, 1080);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(Label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getImage()).getImage());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected static Image getImage()
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = Window.class.getResource("Logo32.png");

        if (imgURL != null)
        {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL).getImage();
        } else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void addText(String Text)
    {
        LabelText = Label.getText();
        LabelText = LabelText.replace("</html>", "");
        if(Text != null)
        {
            Label.setText(LabelText + "<br/>" + Text + "</html>");
        }else
        {
            Label.setText(LabelText + "<br/><br/></html>");
        }
        System.out.println(Label.getText());
        Label.validate();
    }

    public static int InputInt()
    {
        //User Input here
        //Maybe parse into Int
        return output;
    }

    public static String InputText()
    {
        //User Input here
        //Maybe convert to String
        return outputText;
    }
}
```

And the Game.java

```
...
        public void StartGame()
        {
            ErstesSpiel = 1;
            Window.addText("Wähle deine Sprache | Select your language");
            Window.addText("");
            Window.addText("Deutsch (1) | English (2)");
            Window.addText("");
            int var3 = Window.InputInt();
            Window.addText("");
    ....
```

Comment: What you need is a keyboardeventlistener. see http://www.edu4java.com/en/game/game4.html

Comment: Doenst work... I want something like the scanner.nextInt() which can be used with the console but for JFrame...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a JTextField and get input when the user presses enter by using an actionlistener or by a JButton click

Create this  object

```
JTextField UserInputField = new JTextField("");
```

Call this method when user presses enter with an Action Listener ([more on Action Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html))

```
public static int InputInt()
{
    String sInput = UserInputField.getText(); //Gets the string from the JTextField

    int output = Integer.parseInt(sInput.trim()); //Parse string to int

    return output; //Return as int
}
```

If what you want is for the method to auto-run whenever the user inputs a number, you can use a keyboard listener 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html